# Unable to get some keys in redis

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I have loaded my redis instance with an RDB file. I can see all the keys loaded from the count. But i am not able to get some of the keys which are in the list. Its redirecting to some slots and showing nill.

Please help.

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:11212> GET SMRT
-> Redirected to slot [951] located at 10.20.16.117:11211
"SAM~123456~653421~2~R~7,6,5,4,3,2,9,10,11,12,79,"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:11211> GET GREY
-> Redirected to slot [14074] located at 10.20.16.116:11214
(nil)

Comment: What does your redis-cluster configuration look like?

Comment: My Config looks like : appendonly yes
appendfilename "appendonly.aof"
auto-aof-rewrite-percentage 100
auto-aof-rewrite-min-size 64mb
appendfsync everysec no-appendfsync-on-rewrite no  cluster-enabled yes aof-use-rdb-preamble yes